# Mysql returning wrong count of column status

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get list of tickets status "pending", "progress", "completed" as group of month. I am trying this query which gives me wrong result

```
select  
count(id) as tickets,
month(created_at) as month,
(select count(status) from tickets where status =0) as pending,
(select count(status) from tickets where status =1) as progress,
(select count(status) from tickets where status =2) as completed
from tickets 
group by month
```

its returning as following in image

[image: query returning as following]

which is wrong because i have just one ticket in feb. my table is following

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your subqueries have no conditions, they are counting tickets for every month, not just the month you are aggregating for. You can add that constraint to the subqueries, but it is easier to use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(id) as tickets,
       month(created_at) as month,
       sum(status = 0) as pending,
       sum(status = 1) as progress,
       sum(status = 2) as completed
from tickets 
group by month
```

Note since MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context, you can simply sum a boolean expression rather than using an `IF(expression,1,0)` type structure.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select  count(id) as tickets,
month(created_at) as month,
(select count(status) from tickets where status =0 and id=T1.id) as pending,
(select count(status) from tickets where status =1 and id=T1.id) as progress,
(select count(status) from tickets where status =2 and id=T1.id) as completed
from tickets as T1
group by month
```

in your query the subclauses are not associated with the main clause which basically runs the same query for all records.